# jqueryui.com: information about css classes is gone

Tags: jquery-ui

Before `jqueryui.com` got updated, you usually found in the documentation of any widget a list of css classes you could use to manipulate the appearance or it's position. I mean things like *use `ui-button-text` to change xxx*.

It seems to me that this information is now gone or at least I cannot find it.

Does anyone know where I could get these infos for any widget?

Comment: Could you rather explain what you want to do? As is, your question is not about programming itself

Comment: What I mean is the documentation of jQuery UI. In the past (before the layout was updated some weeks ago) the examples and the documentation of the widgets were put together (now they are sperated). And there you could find the "theming" section which explained which css classes you can use to change your widgets. I've found an old jquery-ui-1.8.22 zip file and in the `development-bundle/docs` you have the old contents of the jqueryui.com. For example this screenshot: http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/5514/theming.png sadly, I cannot find this information anymore.

Comment: Yes, but I mean what you want to _implement_ or _build_. If you need the doc, it's not just for knowledge I guess. Could you not just say what you aim to do so that people can share their knowledge about the subject?

Comment: Of course I have projects where I use jquery-ui. But at the moment I am more interested in general knowledge rather than something specific.